# XML/Array to Key value pair in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have following output :

```
<table count="" time="0.010006904602051">
<item>
<id>607</id>
<name>MSPOT6071</name>
<description>Hip Hop / Raps</description>
<type>3</type>
<radio_folder_id/>
<albumart>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_175.jpg
</albumart>
<albumart_300>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_350.jpg
</albumart_300>
<albumart_500>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_500.jpg
</albumart_500>
</item>
<item>
<id>48542614</id>
<name>US Pop - TESTB</name>
<description>Blues</description>
<type>3</type>
<radio_folder_id/>
</item>
</table>
```

I want to read this output in the form of Key value pair and then want to store each value.
for eg i want the value of "name"

Can anyone please help me with the code..I am not getting the clue of how to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simplexml extension functions to achieve your goals. With this extension you can load xml from [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), from [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or from a [html node](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php). Follow the links to get more information about each load function. I will explain here how to load using simplexml_load_file.
This code:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";   
$xml = simplexml_load_file("name.xml");
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Will return this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [count] => 
            [time] => 0.011766910552979
        )

    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 607
                    [name] => MSPOT6071
                    [description] => Hip Hop / Raps
                    [type] => 3
                    [radio_folder_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [albumart] => http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_175.jpg
                    [albumart_300] => http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_350.jpg
                    [albumart_500] => http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_500.jpg
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 48542614
                    [name] => US Pop - TESTB
                    [description] => Blues 
                    [type] => 3
                    [radio_folder_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The information you want, can be accessed like this:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";   
$xml = simplexml_load_file("name.xml");
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($xml->children() as $item){
        $arr = get_object_vars($item);
        foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
            echo "$key => $value" . PHP_EOL;            
        }
    }
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Note it will be accessed as object first. Then you can get all object vars to dynamically navigate through your object attributes.

Comment: I tried the following way the only issue is that it only returns the last results and not all the results.foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    print("Key: ".$key."    Value:".$value."\n");

    foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
     print("SubKey: ".$subKey."    SubValue:".$subValue."\n");
     $this->id=$value['id'];
    }
   }

Comment: I do not have input xml file..so how can i do $xml = simplexml_load_file("name.xml");

Comment: I want to read all the keys and values from my output. I am getting stuck in the code as I am not able to right the correct foreach conditions. I want to right a generic foreach function that will read all the keys and values depending on item[0], [1]....So i want to use item[i]foreach ($result->children() as $key => $value) {
     print("Key: ".$key."    Value:".$value."\n");
     
     print($result->item[0]->name);
     foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
      print("SubKey: ".$subKey."    SubValue:".$subValue."\n");
      //$this->id=$value['id'];
     }
    }

Comment: You are not doing it right. You must work with the object first. See my answer edited to your needs

Answer (score 0):

The

```
<?php

$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<table count="" time="0.010006904602051">
<item>
<id>607</id>
<name>MSPOT6071</name>
<description>Hip Hop / Raps</description>
<type>3</type>
<radio_folder_id/>
<albumart>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_175.jpg
</albumart>
<albumart_300>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_350.jpg
</albumart_300>
<albumart_500>
http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/009/560/0000956027_500.jpg
</albumart_500>
</item>
<item>
<id>48542614</id>
<name>US Pop - TESTB</name>
<description>Blues</description>
<type>3</type>
<radio_folder_id/>
</item>
</table>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach($xml->item as $item)
{
    echo $item->name."<br>";
}

echo $xml->item[0]->name;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Assign your XML string to a variable $xmlstr and so you don't run into incomplete XML document errors make sure you include the following at the top of your XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

Then use the built-in SimpleXML class by passing your XML string $xmlstr to SimpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

Now you can access your XML file as a PHP object using the attributes and methods of the SimpleXML class. In this example we loop over the 'item'(s) in your XML document and print out the 'name' elements:

```
foreach($xml->item as $item)
{
    echo $item->name."<br>";
}
```

I have also include code to access the first item element:

```
echo $xml->item[0]->name;
```

As well as some debugging code view the XML document in a SimpleXML object:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

You access the key or in this case the object property by its name. So in your foreach loop you might do:

```
if($item->name)
{
    echo $item->name;
}
```

or

```
if($item->description)
{
    echo $item->description;
}
```

May the force be with you.

Comment: You should provide an explanation about what this is doing.

Comment: THank you ..this really helped..Now I want to read the key of the value..So I want to verify whether the "name" key is present in my output..how should I get the key?